# Unity build doesn't work specifically on Huawei devices, how to fix or figure this out?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play, wear-os

My first question asked! I have developed a game using Unity3D and published it to google play for mobile devices. The game works on all devices so far except for the Huawei Watch 1st Gen. (yes building Unity games for smartwatches). Short of running out and buying a $200 watch to test and test more,

Does anyone know of any reason why a mobile game would work on literally every device except for one? If so how can I go about figuring this out if answers are from reach?

*UPDATE* I have been given a stack trace from google =)

```
native: pc 00000000005f8278  /data/app/com.stonegolemstudios.combatwear-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
native: pc 0000000000add428  /data/app/com.stonegolemstudios.combatwear-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
```

Not sure what this is but it was part of the crash report.

signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)

Hope this helps to solve the problem.

Comment: How do yo know that it doesn't work on the Huawei Watch 1st Gen, and what do you mean by 'doesn't work'?

Comment: Is there specific hardware that your app requires that is not supported on the `Huawei` watch?

Comment: The google dev team emailed me. The only info given was that it crashes on start-up. Its hardware has nothing notably different from the 2 android wear watches I own.

Answer (score 0):

If its doesnt work on specific device than your device might need update or reset, but if its doesnt work on Huawie smart watches it must be because of your resulation / screen preferances when you compiling your app, and you should check api level as well in order to solve that problem.

I hope this will help you :)